# Why might have SAC headquarters been knocked out already?

Tags: wargames-1983

In the 1983 science fiction film *Wargames*, before turning the final key for the missile launch, Jerry, the commanding officer, demanded that Steve, his subordinate, try to get SAC headquarters on the phone:

> Jerry: Try SAC headquarters on the HF.
>
> Steve: That's not the procedure.
>
> Jerry: Screw the procedure. I want somebody on the phone  before I kill 20 million people.
>
> Steve: I got nothing here. **It might've been knocked out already**.

**Why might have SAC headquarters been knocked out already?**

Comment: I don't have time to make a good answer now, but the SAC had control over Strategic bomber and ICBM, and would be essential to react to a soviet attack. Therefore, it was a strategic target, to be shot as soon as possible

Comment: A minor issue: HF would be "high frequency", a radio, not the telephone.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

SAC is [Strategic Air Command](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategic_Air_Command). During the Cold War, it was responsible for two of the three parts of the nuclear triad: intercontinental ballistic missiles (ICBMs) and nuclear bombers (submarine-launched ballistic missiles (SLBMs) being the third). It was head-quartered at [Offutt Air Force Base](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Offutt_Air_Force_Base#Strategic_Air_Command) near Omaha, Nebraska. In case of a nuclear attack it would be a prime target and as such may already have been struck by the time the order to launch was relayed.

While we (the viewers) later learn it was an exercise, the two men, Jerry and Steve, do not know that at that time. They are somewhere in a bunker, likely safe from everything but a direct hit. They don't know why the order was given, they don't know if it's a pre-emptive strike or a retaliatory one. All they know is the order they get to launch their missiles, presumably (were it not an exercise) to kill millions of people in the USSR. The phone line was likely cut as part of the exercise, to simulate a scenario where a launch order was given while (or shortly before) SAC was struck.

Comment: The novel has a slightly different version; "*Ulmer desperately snatched up a headset, stuck one earpiece to his head. He stepped to a military transmitter and twisted at the channel selector, listening intently. He sighed. “Nothing.” A haunted look invaded his eyes. “They’ve probably been... vaporized.”*"

Answer (score 0):

Actually, this scenario is not possible outside a test like this one.

You might imagine that having your control authority centralized at one well known base would be a bad idea. And of course, that's not how it worked. Command of the strategic forces is centered at SAC, but that's *administratively*.

In terms of actual command flows, there are multiple bases with command authority. Among them are the [Looking Glass aircraft](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operation_Looking_Glass), which at that time were always airborne. The system was decentralized in this fashion specifically to avoid a "decapitation strike" like this scenario entails. There was even a fail-safe option on the fail-safe, a Minuteman missile with radio transmitters that was sent up first in case of an attack and ensured the fire signal went out.

There was no credible scenario in which all command was lost. And such a thing would mean the firing codes couldn't have gone out anyway. Even within the movie universe, one has to use some fairly perverse logic to come up with a scenario under which the release codes were able to reach the bunker but voice channels could not.